# Developing ASP.NET MVC UI Extensions - best approach

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-controls

What are the best practices in developing rich UI extensions for ASP.NET MVC (I mean asynchronous / partial loading, slick effects, skinning etc) ? I saw that Telerik has an MVC suite of extensions, but haven't tried them yet, so I cannot comment on them.

My biggest concern as of the moment is how to structure the code of my extensions so that C#, ASP markup, and JQuery remain separate from each other, yet encapsulated in a way that the extension must be easy to distribute and reuse.

I know that the user control approach had many flaws, yet it sort of allowed application developers to just reference a control, set some parameters and get it going in a few minutes. I'd like to achieve the same kind of portability/reusability as I still keep the code easy to extend  and build upon.

Now, some ideas that come to mind as topics for discussion are:
template helpers vs. extension method helpers or a possible integration
efficient use of jQuery 
- naming conventions - 
- asynchronous action loading - 
etc you can add whatever comes to your mind

Answer (score 0):

The Asp.net MVC specific plugin/module/component question has been asked before:

[What is best practice on ASP.NET MVC projects and extensionable/skinned systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258043/what-is-best-practice-on-asp-net-mvc-projects-and-extensionable-skinned-systems/2258722#2258722)

[ASP.NET MVC "Components"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902/asp-net-mvc-components)

[ASP.NET MVC - How to achieve reusable user controls and maintain DRY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983331/asp-net-mvc-how-to-achieve-reusable-user-controls-and-maintain-dry)

[Custom components and ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155961/custom-components-and-asp-net-mvc/2156250#2156250)

I'd take a look at other approaches that are out there first before becoming pedantic about naming conventions and template vs extension method helpers or whatever ( I don't understand what that means anyway ;) ).